# "An error occurred whilst communicating with the server" or "Error connecting to the server" Moodle 3.7

Tags: php, iis, file-upload, moodle, http-status-code-413

I am getting "An error occurred whilst communicating with the server" or "Error connecting to the server" on a Moodle 3.7 site when I try to upload audio or video files. May be becuase the error shows up in a pop up message no debug messages are displayed even though i enabled it in the settings. Strange thing is previously i was able to upload without such errors.

Action taken so far to relove the issue;
increasing following values in php.ini

```
memory_limit
upload_max_filesize 
post_max_size 
max_input_time
```

increasing uploadReadAheadSize, appConcurrentRequestLimit in IIS

I can see the following error in network tab of the browsers inspector
`repository/repository_ajax.php?action=upload [HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large 448ms]`
or
`course/dndupload.php [HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large 455ms]`
I am only trying to upload an audio in 50M size. Uploading word or PDFs produce no errors. I'm trying to resolve this since yesterday. Any help is greatly appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

I added the following in `web.config` located in `c:\Inetput\wwwroot\WebApp directory` and it worked.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" /> 
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
</system.web>
```